# Set timezone no Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, time

Contenho um site, que nas notícias ele cadastra automaticamente a data e hora, só que quando cadastro, a hora cadastrada fica com 3 horas adiantadas.
Estou pensando que deve ser alguma configuração de Timezone do Codeigniter, alguém sabe onde configuro isto nele?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa tarde.
Eu uso essa linha no `index.php`

> date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

Mas tu pode ler mais em [PHP TimeZone](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php)

Espero ter ajudado! Oss

Answer (score 0):

Adicione esta linha ao autoload.php na pasta do aplicativo:

$autoload['time_zone'] = date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

Answer (score -2):

Codeigniter 4 basta incluir no .env as variaveis

app.defaultLocale = 'pt-br'
app.appTimezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo'